# Java Process Builder runs ffmpeg commands very slowly

Tags: java, cmd, ffmpeg, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I'm trying to run `ffmpeg` in Java using `ProcessBuilder`. I'm on Windows. It works fine. But not sure why it's much slower than when I just run the same command in command prompt or PowerShell.

Why is it? Is there any ways to increase the speed?

```
processBuilder.command("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c","ffmpeg.exe", "-y", "-i", video,"-vf","scale=720:-1","out.mp4");
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
                process = processBuilder.start();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                
                String line="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error in processBuilder. ");
        }
```

Comment: A couple debugging ideas: 1) call ffmpeg.exe directly (no shell) & 2) how fast would it run if you don't capture stderr?

Answer (score 0):

You have two starts, delete the first or the redirect will not work:

```
process = processBuilder.start();
```

If your sub-process is quite verbose the problem may simply be `System.out.println()` as multiple line output to some Windows cmd / terminals can be exceptionally slow. You can verify if this is the case by commenting out the print, or capture to File based output before start:

```
processBuilder.redirectOutput(new File("stdout.log"));
```

Don't forget to add status check at the end and cross check rc with `ffmpeg` documentation:

```
int rc = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Tnx. The two start() was a typo though!